# How do I return a list based on an argument to a function in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Basically, I want to pass an argument to a function and depending on the value, return one of many lists to display on the console. To be specific, this is the code I wrote:

```
student(X):- X = Arpit, X = ["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995].
student(X):- X = Manoj, X = ["Computer_Science", "Black_Mirror", 1996].
student(X):- X = Dhruv, X = ["Civil", "House_of_Cards", 1997].
student(X):- X = Srishti, X = ["Electronics", "Mr_Robot", 1995].
```

The idea is to return one of the four lists, depending on the value of the variable (`Arpit/Manoj/Dhruv/Srishti`). But when I call the function as `student(Arpit)`, it returns:

```
Arpit = ["Mechanical, "Suits", 1995]
```

when I call `student(Manoj/Dhruv/Srishti)` also, it returns the same list, irrespective of the value of the variable. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prolog, you have relations not functions. So your predicate will need two arguments, and you can only bind variables to values once.
Another thing is that variables are denoted with capital letters so you cant just say `X =Arpit` as this means that the vairable `X` is bound to the vairable `Arpit` so you either need to use lowercase names or enclose the name in quotes.

`student(X,Y):- X = "Arpit", Y = ["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995].
student(X,Y):- X = "Manoj", Y = ["Computer_Science", "Black_Mirror", 1996].
student(X,Y):- X = "Dhruv", Y = ["Civil", "House_of_Cards", 1997].
student(X,Y):- X = "Srishti", Y = ["Electronics", "Mr_Robot", 1995].`

```
?- student("Arpit", List).
List = ["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995].
```

You can also generate all pairs with :

```
?- student(Name,List).
Name = "Arpit",
List = ["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995];
```

You can hit space for more results here

Or find the name associated with a list:

```
?- student(Name,["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995]).
Name = "Arpit".
```

Or check if a pair exists at all:

```
?- student("Fred",["Extra", "Shirts", 2010]).
false.
```

Comment: Rather than `student(X,Y):- X = "Arpit", Y = ["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995].` in Prolog it's better to write `student("Arpit",  ["Mechanical", "Suits", 1995]).` It asserts the relationship as a fact rather than a predicate.